# Question on Multiselect Picklist

Tags: formula, multi-select, isblank

I am trying to assign values to a multiselect picklist which also allows users to input a unique value (lots of values).

I would like to create a formula to assign a 1 to all values, and 0 to blank.

My formula is following but i keep getting errors.

```
(isblank(Race_or_Ethnicity__c,0,1)).
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Please include the specific error messages here.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula was almost correct. You simply needed to use an IF keyword:

```
if(isblank(Race_or_Ethnicity__c),0,1)
```

Comment: @JayantDas I was referring to "TEXT", actually... It doesn't work on MPL fields. For some reason, MPL is treated differently from normal picklists.

Comment: Got it. Good to know. Will give it a try.

Comment: Never in my life, I saw someone use MPL properly. Can't create reports filter, cant index , underperforming querries

Comment: thanks so much everyone! I didnt realize you could use IF in an MPL.